# Database connection in SAS using ssh tunneling

Tags: sql, ssh, odbc, sas

I want to know if there is a way to connect to a MySQL database in SAS using SHH tunneling using .ppk file.

I am able to connect to this MySQL database using SQLyog by providing the.ppk file.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this via plink (from the PuTTy package). In my example, I connect to a remote server, but it would also work for localhost w/o all the forwarding.

First, set up your ODBC (32 or 64 bit) data source as you would normally - say you named it DB_SOURCE, with the appropriate driver, listing 127.0.0.1 or localhost as the server, and a local port number (LOCAL_PORT) . Second, use the x command (after adjusting options):

```
options noxwait NOXSYNC;
data _null_; /* set up tunnel to remote db */
    x '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" REMOTE_IP -P 22 -T -l USER_NAME -i c:\users\LOCAL_USER_NAME\.ssh\PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME.ppk -L 127.0.0.1:LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_IP:REMOTE_PORT';
run;
```

Then, do your normal work. For example:

```
libname LIBNAME ODBC datasrc=DB_SOURCE qualifier=DB_TO_USE;
```

Key file Seemed best practice as leaving a password riding around in a plain text SAS program struck me as not good.